# When we refer to a 'Room key', is the room being used as an adjective here? can't I say 'Room's key' instead?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, etymology

What I am trying to find out here is the etymology of the phrase "Room key". Surely, it must have been "room's key" first. When and how did it become "Room key"? and Can I still use "Room's key" instead?

Comment: Consider that German doesn't just use noun attributives, it simply runs nouns together to form long words like *Dampfschifffahrt* (steam ship journey), it seems likely to me (but maybe a proper linguist can give more detail) that noun attributives have been part of English since before English split up from German.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Room" is being used as a [noun attributive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/help/explanatory-notes/dict-attributive-nouns) here. That is, it is a noun that modifies another noun.

These are very common in English, in terms such as "baseball diamond", "horse race", "dog house", etc.

It's not necessary that these constructions evolved from possessive forms.

"Room's key" is not idiomatic English in any scenario that comes to my mind immediately. However it wouldn't be out of place to say "the key to the room" if you prefer.